# Why is my tree-node function producing Null when I run an array through it?

Tags: python, tree, max

I am working on the LeetCode problem [104. Maximum Depth of Binary Tree](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-depth-of-binary-tree/):

> Given the `root` of a binary tree, return *its maximum depth*.
>
> A binary tree's **maximum depth** is the number of nodes along the longest path from the root node down to the farthest leaf node.

My attempt is not working: I first add the `root` to a queue (if `root` is not `None`), and then process it, by adding its children to the queue.

While doing this, I keep a counter, and each time I add a child node, I increment the counter by 1. When both left and right child exist, I will only increment the counter by 1.

```
from collections import deque

class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
        self.val = val
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

class Solution:
    def max_depth(self,root):
        counter = 1
        queue = deque
        
        if not root: 
            return 0
        else:
            queue.append(root)

        while queue:
            root = queue.popleft()

            if root.left:
                queue.append(root.left)
                counter +=1

            if root.right:
                queue.append(root.right)
                if root.left:
                    continue
                else:
                    counter +=1

        return counter
```

However, when I run the above on LeetCode, for an input of say [3,9,20,null,null,15,7], I get 'None' as a result.

Is it because I have structured the function to not take a list as an input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it because I have structured the function to not take a list as an input?

No. This may be confusing, but on LeetCode the raw list representation of the input is translated to an instance of `TreeNode` before your function is called. So you should never have to deal with this list structure. It is merely the common input format that LeetCode uses across the different programming languages. But the conversion to the target language's data structure is done for you before your implementation is called.

Your code produces an error on the first call of `queue.append` because of this line:

```
queue = deque
```

This is wrong, as this makes `queue` a synonym for the *class* `deque`. But it should be an *instance* of it, so do:

```
queue = deque()
```

With that fix, the function does not return `None`.

However, its logic is not correct:

> I keep a counter, and each time I add a child node, I increment the counter by 1. When both left and right child exist, I will only increment the counter by 1.

This practically means that you count the number of nodes that have at least one child, i.e. you count the number of *internal* nodes of the tree.
This is not correct. For instance, the following tree has 7 internal nodes:

```
                 ___ 10 __
                /         \
               5           14
             /   \        /   \
            1     8     12     20
           / \   / \   /  \   /  \
          0   2 6   9 11  13 18  22
```

Obviously, 7 is not the correct answer. It should be 4 in this case.

Your queue-based solution will visit the nodes level by level, but you don't have any information about when you pass from one level to the next.

You can solve this by using two (standard) lists: the first list will have all the nodes from one level, and the second list will collect those from the next level. When that is done you know you have processed one level. Then you make the second list the first, and empty the second. Then you can restart this process for as long as there are nodes to process:

```
class Solution:
    def maxDepth(self, root: TreeNode) -> int:
        counter = 0
        queue = []
        
        if root: 
            queue.append(root)

        while queue:
            counter +=1
            nextlevel = []
            
            for root in queue:
                if root.left:
                    nextlevel.append(root.left)
                if root.right:
                    nextlevel.append(root.right)
            queue = nextlevel

        return counter
```

Making it a bit more compact, it can be:

```
class Solution:
    def maxDepth(self, root: TreeNode) -> int:
        counter = 0
        if root: 
            queue = [root]
            while queue:
                counter +=1
                queue = [root.left for root in queue if root.left
                        ] + [root.right for root in queue if root.right]
        return counter
```

You can also go for a depth-first traversal instead of the breadth-first traversal you were going for:

```
class Solution:
    def maxDepth(self, root: TreeNode) -> int:
        return 1 + max(self.maxDepth(root.left), 
                       self.maxDepth(root.right)) if root else 0
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation trincot. One question, does the root node sit on level 0 or 1? Because on google it says level 0 but in books I have read it says level 1.

Comment: There is different terminology here. The height of a node, the height of a tree, the depth of a node, the depth of a tree, the level of a node... There are different definitions for them. Important here is that the LeetCode challenge gives a clear definition of what they expect as maximum depth: it is the *number of nodes* on the longest path from root to a leaf. So if the given tree has just one node (the root) the return value must be 1.